# How to count the total of nested foreach in first row in laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, foreach

My data set and coding are listed below.

```
[  
   {  
      "color":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "color":"yellow"
         },
         {  
            "id":2,
            "color":"red"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "color":[  
         {  
            "id":3,
            "color":"blue"
         },
         {  
            "id":4,
            "color":"green"
         }
      ]
   }
]

@foreach ($items as $item)
    @foreach($item->color as $color)
       <p>{{$color->color}}</p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

What I want:

yellow 1/4

red    2/4

blue   3/4

green  4/4

How can I count the total in every row?

Comment: What if you count the sequences separately?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to take an array :

```
@php
    $color_counts = array();
@endphp
```

Than in for loop you can count colors@foreach ($items as $item)

```
 @foreach($item->color as $color)
      @php
        if(isset($color_counts[$color->color]) && $color_counts[$color->color]!=null){
          $color_counts[$color->color]['count'] += 1;
        }
        else {
          $color_counts[$color->color]['count'] = 1;
          $color_counts[$color->color]['color_name'] = $color->color;
        }
      @endphp
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Now you can get colors and its count in `$color_counts` array.

Note : You can do this thing in a controller and pass it to view

Answer (score 0):

you can You Laravel collection count method

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4]);

$collection->count();
```

like that
for more information follow this link :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-count

Answer (score 0):

I created a similar JSON code just to show you the way of how to make it work.

```
[{"id":1,"color":"blue"},{"id":2,"color":"red"},{"id":3,"color":"red"},{"id":4,"color":"green"},{"id":5,"color":"red"},{"id":6,"color":"blue"}]
```

```php
    $colors = Color::all(); // Model contains 6 random colors
    $countAllColors = count($colors);
    $colorNames = $colors->countBy('color');
    foreach ($colorNames->all() as $key => $value) {
        $values = $key . $value . '/' . $countAllColors . "\n";
        echo $values; // output will be: blue2/6 red3/6 green1/6
    }
```

you might noticed that I'm using [countby](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-countBy) method to see how much do we have repeated color `item in the array`.

however, if you want to do it in `blade` template, just copy the code below and paste it in your blade template

```
@php
 $colors = '[{"id":1,"color":"blue"},{"id":2,"color":"red"},{"id":3,"color":"red"},{"id":4,"color":"green"},{"id":5,"color":"red"},{"id":6,"color":"blue"}]';
 $colors = json_decode($colors, true);
 $colors = collect($colors);
 $countAllColors = count($colors);
 $colorNames = $colors->countBy('color');
@endphp

<div>
    @foreach ($colorNames->all() as $key => $value)
       <b> {{ $key . $value . '/' . $countAllColors .'   ' }} </b> <br>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

output

blue2/6
red3/6
green1/6

for the nesting problem, you might want to take a look of this [pulck](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-pluck) method.

I hope you find it useful